# How can I use Axios interceptors to add some headers to responses?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, create-react-app

In my Reactjs app , I want to add an interceptor which can append some headers to some backend responses

So, I tried this :

```
    export default function App() {
      axios.interceptors.response.use(
        (config)=> {
          config.headers['myheader'] = 'myvalue'; // <-- THIS IS MY CUSTOM HEADERS
          return config;
        },
        (error) => {
          // ON ERREOR
        })
       ......
      );
```

And I suppose like that that my header would be append in every back-end response. But that doesn't seem to work.

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Add a request interceptor**

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        Promise.reject(error)
});
```

**Add a response interceptor**

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => { // block to handle success case
    return response
 }, function (error) { // block to handle error case
    const originalRequest = error.config;
 
    if (error.response.status === 401 && originalRequest.url ===
 'http://dummydomain.com/auth/token') { // Added this condition to avoid infinite loop 

 
        // Redirect to any unauthorised route to avoid infinite loop...
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
 
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) { // Code inside this block will refresh the auth token
 
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const refreshToken = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // Write the  logic  or call here the function which is having the login to refresh the token.
        return axios.post('/auth/token',
            {
                "refresh_token": refreshToken
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    localStorage.setItem('auth_token',res.data);
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
                    return axios(originalRequest);
                }
            })
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

[Click here](https://jsonworld.com/blog/how-to-use-interceptor-with-react-to-set-auth-header-with-api-request) to see the topic in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Hey the reason thats not working because you are calling use method to update the ***repsonse*** headers but to be able to send headers to your backend apis you need to call the use method from ***request*** object. Here's how you can do :

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  function handleRequestInterceptor(config) {
    const modifiedConfig = {
      ...config,
      headers: {
        myheader: "myvalue",  <=== your custom headers like auth etc.
        ...config.headers,
      },
    };
    return modifiedConfig;
  },
  function handleRequestInterceptorError(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: i don t want tu update my request headrs , i want to add a headr for mybackend response

Comment: @firasKoubaa but why do you want to do that ? just wanted to know the use case that

Comment: i want to add the CORS header for some backends servers that i wouldn t change code (already deployed solutions) , all that for experimental purposes

Comment: @firasKoubaa is it like you want to bypass CORS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        const edited_response = response;
        edited_response.headers["custom_header"] = "test";
        return edited_response;
      },
      function (error) {
        // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
        // Do something with response error
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
```